# Method to give number of favorites in has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `User` model where the users can "favorite" each other.  I'm achieving this through a `Favoriting` model as a `has_many through` relationship to reference `User` to itself:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favoriting
  has_many :favorites, through: :favoritings, source: :favorited
  has_many :favoriteds, class_name: "Favoriting", foreign_key: "favorited_id"
  has_many :favoriters, through: :favoriteds, source: :user
  ...
end

class Favoriting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, :class_name => 'User'
  ...
end
```

This all works great.  I can do `u.favorites` and get a user's favorites, and I can do `u.favoriters` to get the users that have favorited `u`.  I can also do `u.favorites_count` to get the number of favorites.

However, I can't do `u.favoriters_count` to get the number of users that have favorited `u`.

Any idea if there is access to a built-in method for `favoriters_count` or even `favoriteds_count` with this type of DB relationship?  I could write my own but would rather keep the code base as simple and "Rails-y" as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered adding a `counter_cache` alongside with a `favoritings_count` column?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without additional DB operations.  I will already have the `User` model loaded, so I will need to read from a counter column on the `User` model.

Comment: have you considered adding a `counter_cache`?

Comment: I've tried on both `belongs_to` calls, separately and together.  It just throws errors about lack of `favoritings_count` column. I'd rather not rename the tracking column to that, but I may give it a try soon.

Comment: OK just added `favoritings_count` column along with `counter_cache: true` on the `belongs_to :favorited` line. Thanks for your help -- happy to give you the solution if you update your answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the methods added by `has_many` are listed in 4.3.1 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and do not include a method by this name.

Comment: This sounds right to me, but it also doesn't list `favorites_count` in the documentation, and I have access to that method even without `counter_cache: true` defined on the `Favoriting` model...

Comment: I know you came up with defining a `favoritings_count` column and using `counter_cache`, but would you mind checking where `favorites_count` is defined (e.g. `user.method(:favorites_count)` and `user.method(:favorites_count).source_location`?